# Trying to use Draw2d jar for simple graph

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, draw

I am creating a plugin project where I need to draw a simple graph having X,Y coordinates and based on the values, the graph should be plotted. I decided to use draw2d jar file and have the setup ready like I am am able to draw rectangluar shapes etc.. But I don't know how to create X , Y coordinate lines and draw the graph ?

don't know which classes will be used ..... the sample code will be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

I find it really difficult to used plain draw2d for plotting the data. SWT XYGRaph is a library based on draw2d and to me, it is much easier to use. I would recommend that.